# URLRequestDefaults in flex 4.6

Tags: apache-flex, find

Can't find the class URLRequestDefaults in flex 4.6. Where is it gone?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Be sure that the airglobal.swc library has been included.  If this is within a library project, look at the project's properties. Be sure to check off "Include Adobe AIR libraries" in the Flex Library Compiler section.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the Adobe JIRA, some people complained by its lack of documentation, whilst other complained that it didn't work at all.

I think it was unfinished and got removed in 4.5.